# Cannot find the Start Button under CodeWhisperer in AWS Toolkit

Tags: intellij-idea, amazon-codewhisperer

I am trying to use CodeWhisperer in the AWS Toolkit for JetBrains, but I don't see the Start button. I have an option to Request Preview Access, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a workaround?

I have tried looking at the Getting Started page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codewhisperer/latest/userguide/whisper-setup-indv-devs.html and that shows a Start Button under CodeWhisperer.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the IDE to the latest version and then upgrading to the latest version of the toolkit shows the Start Button under CodeWhisperer. Ref: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/3684